# How is this an isomorphism?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

$\newcommand\O{\mathcal O}$I was reading Silverman and Tate's Rational Points on Elliptical Curves. In page 21 of the same book it was written

> We also want to mention that there is nothing special about our choice of $\O$; if we choose a different point $\O'$ to be the zero element of our group, then we get a group with exactly the same structure. In fact, the map
>   $$P\longmapsto P+(\O'-\O)$$
>   is an isomorphism from the group "$C$ with zero element $\O$" to the group "$C$ with zero element $\O'$."

My question is how is this an isomorphism between the points? Let $\phi$ be the aforesaid map. To prove it's an isomorpshim we have to show it's a bijection first. That is easily done.
Now I have to prove that $$\phi(P)+_{\O'}\phi(Q)=\phi(P+_\O Q) $$

Comment: I think you have to take the operation, $\#$, in the new group, to be $A\#B=A+B-(O'-O)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think the point is that choosing $\mathcal O'$ as the zero element gives a group $(C,\sharp)$ and it *turns out* that $P\,\sharp\,Q = P+Q-(\mathcal O'-\mathcal O)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\O{\mathcal O}$Let $C$ be an elliptic curve and $\ast:C\times C\to C$ be the operation that takes $P,Q\in C$ to the third point $P\ast Q$ on the line through $P$ and $Q$. If we choose a zero element $\O$, we obtain a group $(C,+)$ with
$$
P+Q = \O \ast (P\ast Q).
$$
Picking a different zero $\O'$ gives a group $(C,\oplus)$ with
\begin{align}
P\oplus Q = \O' \ast (P\ast Q).
\end{align}

From these definitions, we have
$$
(P\oplus Q)\ast\O' = P\ast Q = (P+Q)\ast\O.
$$
Thus, by applying $\ast\,\O$ to this equation, we get
$$
(P\oplus Q)+\O' = P+Q.
$$
We conclude
$$
P\oplus Q = P+Q-\O'.
$$

Now let's check if
\begin{align}
\Phi : (C,+) &\longrightarrow (C,\oplus) \\
P &\longmapsto P+(\O'-\O)
\end{align}
is a homorphism. First note that $\O'-\O=\O'$ since $\O$ is the zero element in $(C,+)$, so
\begin{align}
\Phi(P+Q) &= P+Q+\O' = (P+\O')+(Q+\O')-\O' \\&= \Phi(P)+\Phi(Q)-\O' = \Phi(P)\oplus\Phi(Q).
\end{align}

Comment: So can we say that the map is $P\mapsto P+\mathcal{O}$ ?

Comment: If you mean $P\mapsto P+\O'$, yes. That's how I used the map in the calculation.

Comment: Is there some reason why does the authors add the redundant term?

Comment: That's a question only the author can answer. I don't see any reason.